# when a box is checked I want to another one to be chek

Tags: nsis

I have the next two section

```
Section /o "Communications Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Communications Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section  /o "Control System Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Control System Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
```

and in process of installation, when a user  check  the second one"Control System Toolbox", automatically the first one "Communications Toolbox" I want to be check, and in that moment to be displayed a message " To install Control System Toolbox you need also to install  "Communications Toolbox". 
How I can do this thing?

I tried to put a textbox in "Control System Toolbox" :

```
Section  /o "Control System Toolbox"
     MessageBox MB_OK "Do you want to stay in the license page?" IDOK 
     Abort  
FileWrite $9 "product=Control System Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
```

I don't understand why after I push the button OK, didn't turned in previous page ??

Comment: You talk about returning to a previous page but there is no page code in your example, how are we supposed to know what you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

**A)** Enforce the requirements on the component page:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section /o "Main Component" SID_MAIN
DetailPrint "Installing Main Component..."
SectionEnd

Section /o "Bonus feature" SID_BONUS
DetailPrint "Installing bonus Component..."
SectionEnd

!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function .OnSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_BONUS}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_MAIN} ; The main component is required when installing the bonus component
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${SID_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
${Else}
    !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${SID_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

You can also use section groups like [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094651/3501) in your other question.

**B)** Use a MessageBox during the install phase (code in sections are executed on the InstFiles page) and force a component to be installed if required:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section "" ; Hidden section
Call EnsureRequiredSections ; We have to call a function because SID_MAIN has not been defined yet
SectionEnd

Section "Main Component" SID_MAIN
DetailPrint "Installing Main Component..."
SectionEnd

Section /o "Bonus feature" SID_BONUS
DetailPrint "Installing bonus Component..."
SectionEnd

!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function EnsureRequiredSections
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_BONUS}
${AndIfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_MAIN}
    MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "Main Component is required when installing the Bonus feature, do you want to install both?" IDNO no
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_MAIN}
    Goto done
    no:
    !insertmacro UnSelectSection ${SID_BONUS}
    done:
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```