# how I can do a section in other section?

Tags: nsis

I want to make a section in other section, how I can do this thing ?

```
Section  /o "Control System Toolbox"

     Section   "Communications Toolbox"
     SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Control System Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
FileWrite $9 "product=Control System Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can organize sections in section groups. The groups cannot execute code but you can put hidden sections in them:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

SectionGroup /e "Main Component"

Section "" SID_MAIN
DetailPrint "Installing Main Component..."
SectionEnd

Section /o "Bonus feature" SID_BONUS
DetailPrint "Installing bonus Component..."
SectionEnd

SectionGroupEnd

!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function .OnSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_BONUS}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_MAIN} ; The main component is required when installing the bonus component
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: and you know how i can verify if a box is checked  or not ? and if is checked  another one to be check

Comment: ${SectionIsSelected} checks if a section is checked and SelectSection adds a check...

Comment: i need to put this in a function or in a section ?

Comment: That depends on when you want the action to occur, all code in sections are executed only on the InstFiles page...